# What's the reasoning behind non-seasonal ARIMA model lag-order bounds?

Tags: arima, lags, bounds

I read some papers on the non-seasonal ARIMA model, and the consensus I've seen is that for ARIMA(p, d, q), p and q should not be greater than 3, maybe 5. What's the reasoning for that? Is it for efficiency? I ask because intuitively, I would think that you want p and q to be very high to get more accurate metrics, as they are reading more data to make the next prediction that way.